# white space above tableview while using viewpager

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a controller where I am using a viewpager and content is displayed in form of tableview. If I go to that controller from my homepage everything works fine but if I go to that controller from my slider, then a white space comes above the first element of the tableview in all my viewpager tabs.I don't know whether its a viewpager issue or tableviews' or sliders'.

Comment: Can you show some screenshots ?

Comment: Try to change top constraint of your UITableView to "top layout guide", not "superview". And this constraint should be equal to 0.

If it doesn't help attach some screenshots of your view controller with table view.

Answer (score 0):

You need to adjust the insets when choosing the relevant view controller in the storyboard as follows:

[image]

Comment: You need to uncheck it.